# case-fold-search apparently not taking effect in re-search-forward

Tags: regular-expressions, case-folding

I wrote the following command to do a regexp replacement in a region.

```
(defun camel-case-to-underscore (a b &optional use-dash)
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (let ((sep (if use-dash "-" "_"))
          (case-fold-search t))
      (goto-char a)
      (while (re-search-forward "\\([[a-z]\\)\\([A-Z]\\)" b t)
        (replace-match (concat (match-string 1) sep
                               (downcase (match-string 2))))
        (incf b (length sep))))))
```

However, `case-fold-search` appears to not be affecting `re-search-forward`, causing undesired results:

```
thisIsAnExampleInCamelCase => t_hi_sI_SA_NE_Xa_mp_le_in_ca_me_lC_As_e
```

What is wrong with my use of `case-fold-search`?

GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.10) of 2017-10-09

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is wrong with my use of `case-fold-search`?

You've set it to `t` instead of `nil`.

> `case-fold-search` is a variable defined in `C source code`.
>   [...]
>   Non-`nil` if searches and matches should ignore case.

Hence `nil` means case-sensitive, and anything else means case-insensitive.

Comment: yes, thanks. I forgot about that and was interpreting `case-fold-search` as sommething like `case-sensitive-search`